# Copied or restored contents of one Azure Storage Account to another

Tags: azure, database-mirroring, azure-storage

Has anyone copied or restored contents of one Azure Storage Account to another? We have created a PowerShell script using AzCopy to do this. But, the storage account that has over 5,000 containers (~350GB) data taking more than 13 hrs with some data failed to copy. We are not able to use GRS option due to application limitation. Anyone have any tips or suggestions on this?

Note: Both storage accounts are in the same Subscription and same tenant. AzCopy is working , but it is taking very long time. We are looking if there are any alternative options to copy/transfer the data little quicker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Increase Concurrency

If you're uploading or downloading files, use the `AZCOPY_CONCURRENCY_VALUE` environment variable to increase the number of concurrent requests that can occur on your machine. Set this variable as high as possible without compromising the performance of your machine.

### Turn off logging

If you're uploading or downloading files, consider setting the `--check-length` of your copy and sync commands to false. This prevents AzCopy from verifying the length of a file after a transfer.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy-optimize